# Is “It was that year that...” grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, past-perfect

I don't know if this sentence is grammatical and natural:

> I have written a novel. It was that year that I entered university, and finished Beauvoir's *Le Deuxieme Sexe* (1949) in the library.

Would it be better to say it this way?:

> I wrote my novel the year that I entered university, and finished Beauvoir's *Le Deuxieme Sexe* (1949) in the library.

Comment: The second is far easier to parse. Go with that one.

Answer (score 0):

Anybody is free to disagree with me, but "I wrote my novel the year that I entered university" sounds better in my opinion.

My problem with the 1st option is that the two sentences seem... disconnected. Imagine if your parents introduced you to a cousin you never met. You're related to them, sure, but they're a complete stranger.